# Error: Query: Resource id #4

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, fpdf, sqlsrv

Working on to convert my fpdf from MYSQL to SQL-Server but getting this error:

```
Error: 
Query: Resource id #4
```

In my code I have changed all of from MYSQL to sqlsrv:

generate-pdf.php

```
<form action='' method='Post'/>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Generer rapport'>

</form>



<?php

require('mysql_table.php');

 $timezone = "Europe/Oslo";
 date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
 $format="%H%M%S";
$strf=strftime($format);

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{


class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{


function Header()
{
    //Title
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
    $this->Cell(0,6,'Measurement',0,1,'C');
    $this->Ln(10);
    //Ensure table header is output
    parent::Header();
}
}

//Connect to database
$conn_array = array (
"UID" => "sa",
"PWD" => "root",
"Database" => "chart",
) ;
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('BILAL' , $conn_array);


$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table($conn, "SELECT PH, Temperature FROM chartgoogle");
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Output($downloadfilename."$strf.pdf"); 
header('Location: '.$downloadfilename."$strf.pdf");
}
?>
```

mysql_table.php

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_MySQL_Table extends FPDF
{
var $ProcessingTable=false;
var $aCols=array();
var $TableX;
var $HeaderColor;
var $RowColors;
var $ColorIndex;



function Footer()
{
    //Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-10);
    //Arial italic 12
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
    //Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'',0,0,'C');
}



function Header()
{
    //Print the table header if necessary
    if($this->ProcessingTable)
        $this->TableHeader();
}

function TableHeader()
{
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $this->SetX($this->TableX);
    $fill=!empty($this->HeaderColor);
    if($fill)
        $this->SetFillColor($this->HeaderColor[0],$this->HeaderColor[1],$this->HeaderColor[2]);
    foreach($this->aCols as $col)
        $this->Cell($col['w'],6,$col['c'],1,0,'C',$fill);
    $this->Ln();
}

function Row($data)
{
    $this->SetX($this->TableX);
    $ci=$this->ColorIndex;
    $fill=!empty($this->RowColors[$ci]);
    if($fill)
        $this->SetFillColor($this->RowColors[$ci][0],$this->RowColors[$ci][1],$this->RowColors[$ci][2]);
    foreach($this->aCols as $col)
        $this->Cell($col['w'],5,$data[$col['f']],1,0,$col['a'],$fill);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->ColorIndex=1-$ci;
}

function CalcWidths($width,$align)
{
    //Compute the widths of the columns
    $TableWidth=0;
    foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
    {
        $w=$col['w'];
        if($w==-1)
            $w=$width/count($this->aCols);
        elseif(substr($w,-1)=='%')
            $w=$w/100*$width;
        $this->aCols[$i]['w']=$w;
        $TableWidth+=$w;
    }
    //Compute the abscissa of the table
    if($align=='C')
        $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
    elseif($align=='R')
        $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
    else
        $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;
}

function AddCol($field=-1,$width=-1,$caption='',$align='L')
{
    //Add a column to the table
    if($field==-1)
        $field=count($this->aCols);
    $this->aCols[]=array('f'=>$field,'c'=>$caption,'w'=>$width,'a'=>$align);
}

function Table($query,$prop=array())
{

$conn_array = array (
"UID" => "sa",
"PWD" => "root",
"Database" => "chart",
) ;

$conn = sqlsrv_connect('BILAL' , $conn_array);
    //Issue query
$res=sqlsrv_query($conn, '$query') or die('Error: '.mysql_error()."<BR>Query: $query");


    //Add all columns if none was specified
    if(count($this->aCols)==0)
    {
        $nb=sqlsrv_num_fields($res);
        for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
            $this->AddCol();
    }
    //Retrieve column names when not specified
    foreach($this->aCols as $i=>$col)
    {
        if($col['c']=='')
        {
            if(is_string($col['f']))
                $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst($col['f']);
            else
                $this->aCols[$i]['c']=ucfirst(sqlsrv_get_field($res,$col['f']));
        }
    }
    //Handle properties
    if(!isset($prop['width']))
        $prop['width']=0;
    if($prop['width']==0)
        $prop['width']=$this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;
    if(!isset($prop['align']))
        $prop['align']='C';
    if(!isset($prop['padding']))
        $prop['padding']=$this->cMargin;
    $cMargin=$this->cMargin;
    $this->cMargin=$prop['padding'];
    if(!isset($prop['HeaderColor']))
        $prop['HeaderColor']=array();
    $this->HeaderColor=$prop['HeaderColor'];
    if(!isset($prop['color1']))
        $prop['color1']=array();
    if(!isset($prop['color2']))
        $prop['color2']=array();
    $this->RowColors=array($prop['color1'],$prop['color2']);
    //Compute column widths
    $this->CalcWidths($prop['width'],$prop['align']);
    //Print header
    $this->TableHeader();
    //Print rows
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
    $this->ColorIndex=0;
    $this->ProcessingTable=true;
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
        $this->Row($row);
    $this->ProcessingTable=false;
    $this->cMargin=$cMargin;
    $this->aCols=array();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what does it have to do with SQL Server.

Comment: I changed all the mysql to equlent to sqlsrv, with mysql it worked fine but i'm very unsure why it errors. Because it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing wrong parameters to your Table() method.

This is what the method expects, a query and an array of properties:

```
Table($query,$prop=array())
```

This is what your passing, a connection instance and a query.

```
$pdf->Table($conn, "SELECT PH, Temperature FROM chartgoogle");
```

Try changing above to,

```
$pdf->Table("SELECT PH, Temperature FROM chartgoogle");
```

Comment: @user3185936 Are you making this change in file, generate-pdf.php? And in this line? //First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table($conn, "SELECT PH, Temperature FROM chartgoogle");

Comment: Made it, and now gets: Error: 
Query: SELECT PH, Temperature FROM chartgoogle

Comment: The only changes i did in mysql_table was to change mysql to sqlsrv equlent functions, I hope that is not erroring.

Comment: @user3185936 Check the query now. Do you the table chartgoogle in your database? And the columns PH and Temperature? Run the query on your database and see what you get.

Comment: The sql query works just fine as you see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6l9mii61rx0gij/should.png

Comment: @user3185936 Is sqlsrv_connect('BILAL' , $conn_array); BILAL your SQL server name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50894/discussion-between-jay-bhatt-and-user3185936)